# Clickable potentiometer?

Tags: potentiometer

I am trying to design a user interface that consists of several knobs which can turn (duh), be momentarily depressed (clicked), and can be backlit, based on whether they have been clicked or not.

I was thinking of finding some sort of 'clickable' potentiometer and mounting an LED next to it, underneath a semi-transparent shield of some sort.

However, I have had no luck finding these 'clickable' potentiomenters and I also thought it might be somewhat difficult to configure the LED properly as I described.

Does any sort of potentiometer exists? Is there a different route altogether that I should be taking to get the knob, click, and backlit functionality that I want?

Comment: there is something called capaciative touch sensors, which are transparent. 

You may use one of those and a JK FF to toggle the status.
I don't have specific experience with that, so somebody will post the answer.

Comment: @sandun - I don't think capacitive sensors fit the "knobs which can turn" requirement.

Comment: Have a look into knobs made by OKW: http://www.okwenclosures.com/products/okw/star-knobs.htm

Comment: What about a Rotatory encoder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Incremental encoders** often have a haptic detent, and most have a push-button built-in. The detent momentum to overcome the detents may vary from hardly feelable to a clear click. There are also encoders which run smoothly, without detents. Most encoders have between 12 and 30 detents (and also pulses) per revolution.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be a potentiometer, Sparkfun sells a part that matches your description almost perfectly: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10982

Comment: Encoders, and the linked item, are just what I'm looking for! When I see the word 'detent' on websites, does that mean it clicks on push down, or are those clicks you feel when rotating the item?

Comment: Detents are the clicks for rotating

Answer (score 1):

"Clickable" in terms that the parts industry uses usually means "tact" ... so if you search for ["potentiometer with tact"](http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/potentiometer-with-tact-switch.html) you get some results.